# IBM Cognos Analytics with jQuery/DataTables drawn or setData function problem

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

The following JavaScript works fine if I pass `t_dataSet` into DataTable but does not work (e.g no data) if I instead pass `this.dataSet`.

```
define( ['jquery', 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'], function($, Datatables) {
"use strict";

function DatatablesSimpleList() {}

DatatablesSimpleList.prototype.draw = function( oControlHost ) {

    let htmlElement = oControlHost.container;
    htmlElement.innerHTML = '<table id="datatable_example" class="display" width="100%"></table>';

    var t_dataSet = [
        [ "Tiger Nixon" ],
        [ "Garrett Winters"],
        [ "Ashton Cox"]
    ];

    $(function () {
        $('#datatable_example').DataTable({
            data: t_dataSet,        // this works
            //data: this.dataSet,   // this does not work
            columns: [{ title: "Name" }]
        });

    });
};

DatatablesSimpleList.prototype.setData = function( oControlHost, oDataStore ) {

    this.dataSet = [
        [ "Tiger Nixon" ],
        [ "Garrett Winters"],
        [ "Ashton Cox"]
    ];
};

return DatatablesSimpleList;
```

});

Any ideas on why this is not working as expected?